# Разное поведение переменных при require (Область видимости переменной)

Tags: php

В документации сказано

> В большинстве случаев все переменные PHP имеют только одну область
>   видимости. Эта единая область видимости охватывает также включаемые
>   (include) и требуемые (**require**) файлы.

Я же в своем примере получаю ошибку/предупреждение, что в файле **controllers/index.php**

> Notice: Undefined variable: app on line 4

Объясните, почему так проиходит? Переменная `$task` работает нормально.

p.s. Если обьявить в файле `global $app;` или заменить `Route::load . . .`
на `require 'controllers/index.php';` все работает.

**index.php**

```
require 'core/bootstrap.php';

Router::load('routes.php')
    ->direct(Request::uri(), Request::method()); //require controllers/index.php
```

**bootstrap.php**

```
$app = [];
$app['config'] = require 'config.php';

require 'Request.php';
require 'Router.php';
require 'database/Connection.php';
require 'database/QueryBuilder.php';

$app['database'] = new QueryBuilder(
    Connection::make($app['config']['database'])
);
```

**controllers/index.php**

```
// global $app;
$tasks = $app['database']->selectAll('tasks'); //4 строка

require 'public/index.view.php';
```

**public/index.view.php**

```
<?php require 'partials/header.php'; ?>

<h1>Home page</h1>

<?php if (!is_null($tasks)) : ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($tasks as $t) : ?>
            <li><?= $t->text; ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php require 'partials/footer.php'; ?>
```

**Router.php**

```
class Router {
    protected $routes = [];

    public static function load($file)
    {
        $router = new static;

        require $file;

        return $router;
    }

    public function define($routes)
    {
        $this->routes = $routes;
    }

    public function direct($uri, $requestMethod)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($uri, $this->routes[$requestMethod])) {
            require $this->routes[$requestMethod][$uri];
        } else {
            require 'public/404.php';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$app` объявлена в глобальной области видимости, а require вы делаете внутри функции класса load. Всё, что в этом require, получает область видимости класса, поэтому `$app` там и не видна.

Вы можете рассматривать любой include или require как ручную вставку куска кода в требуемое место. Вот вставьте руками код `$task = $app...` в функцию load. Вам же понятно, что внутри load это совсем другая переменная `$app`, не имеющая к глобальной `$app` никакого отношения?

Вот и при require происходит ровно то же самое.